# Graphics2d Stuff

Tags: java, graphics

Hey i am new to this whole coding scene and i was wondering if there was a way to this:

```
Graphics2D g = bufferedImage.getGraphics();
```

In a similar fashion to how you would do this:

```
int j = Integer.parseint(JOptionPane.showInputDialog);
```

Here is all of my code(Sorry i know its messy):

```
public class Drawing extends Canvas {
    public static void main (String[]args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(800, 400);//height in pixles
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//closed program
        Canvas canvas = new Drawing();
        canvas.setBackground(Color.black);
        canvas.setSize(800, 400);
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private Image createImageWithText() {
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(200,200,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g = bufferedImage.getGraphics();
        Image greenskull = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\Users\\Powell Design\\Pictures\\Saved Pictures\\greenskull");
        //gets image from c drive
        g.drawImage(greenskull);

        return bufferedImage;
    }


}
```

Comment: You want to "case" `Graphics` to `Graphics2D` - `Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)bufferedImage.getGraphics();`

Comment: I would encourage you to read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) - *"`getGraphics` - This method returns a `Graphics2D`, but is here for backwards compatibility. **`createGraphics` is more convenient**, since it is declared to return a `Graphics2D`."*

Comment: * You want to "cast" 

Comment: Don't use `Canvas`.  Draw on a `JPanel` instead.  And when you do, make certain you override `paintComponent(Graphics g)`.